# Read archived file from a Jenkins last successful build remotely

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins job i am archiving xml report files.
I want to read the archived xml report files form the last successful build using python program. Is there any way to perform this.

I can reach to those file using below public **VIEW URL (not API URL)** but can not read them as files have dynamic name (appended date & time). Do we have any API which can return me this xml data.

http://MY-URL/jenkins/job/Services/job/{JOB-NAME}/job/{BRANCH-NAME}/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/newman/newman-run-report.xml

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you read the file in the browser? Did you try to curl/wget the same url (with the necessary credentials)? What do you mean by "can not read the data"?

Comment: i have archived xml file in Jenkins job & i want to read the content of that xml file in remotely in using Python program.

Comment: And what exactly does not work? Can you send a request to Jenkins? Do you recieve an error? What error do you encounter?

Comment: I am looking for some way to read the data of xml file archived in Jenkins workspace. (do not see any error)

Comment: the URL i gave in description in VIEW URL of Jenkins not the API URL.

Comment: Okay, so just go to the job page where the artifact (or one of them) is shown. There are two links one with the artifact name the other with "view". Right click on the artifact link > "Copy link location". You can then use this link (with some authorization) to read the artifact.

Comment: Yes that is correct but how can i handle it if the file names are dynamic (not static)

Comment: How about renaming it to a static name during the pipeline runtime?

Comment: during pipeline run it does not matter my python program reads it when the pipeline had been completed (and we need to have dynamic name because there are multiple newman xml report are present in side newman directory)